# python mbox unlock not working

Tags: python, email, mbox

I am using this script to remove messages from an inbox.

```
if(not debug):
  logging.debug("removing messages")
  all_mail.lock()
  for message in all_mail:
    all_mail.remove(message)
  all_mail.flush()
  all_mail.unlock()
all_mail.close()
```

After running this script once, I notice that there is still a lock file in `/var/spool/mail`. If I try running the script again, I get a fairly predictable exception: `mailbox.ExternalClashError: dot lock unavailable`

So it seems like all_mail.unlock() is not working, but I'm not really sure what more to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script should raise an exception at `all_mail.remove(message)` and because of it never reaches the `unlock` call. A `mbox` as important differences from a normal dict, and here is your problem:

> The default Mailbox iterator iterates over **message representations, not keys** as the default dictionary iterator does.

That means that `for message in all_mail:` makes `msg` contains a `mboxMessage` instead of a key and the `remove` raises a `KeyError` exception.

Fix is simple:

```
for message in all_mail.iterkeys():
    all_mail.remove(message)
```